# Strong Induction Questions

Tags: induction

Are there any proofs that cannot be done using mathematical induction, but can be done using strong induction?

Is the proof of every integer≥2 is divisible by a prime?

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Proof of the Fibonacci sequence about what?

Comment: i changed the example question. sorry about that, strong induction is confusing to understand.

Answer (score 1):

One can prove strong induction using ordinary induction; so any proof that uses strong induction could be rewritten, if desired, to use only ordinary induction.

Comment: But it can still be proven using MI, right? I'm trying to find proofs that cannot be solved using MI, and only able to be solved using Strong Induction.

Comment: And @Greg Martin has explained to you why that is impossible.